# How to replace old PCIex NIC to Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, hardware, nic

This might seems a silly question for mostly system managers but I haven't found a well documented article on the web about it. The thing is, I would like to replace the old 10/100Mbps PCi-ex network adapter for a new Giga network adapter, same PCi-ex slot, to an Ubuntu server in production.

A given similar question by another user exposed the issues regarding updating all the configuration involving the old NIC across the whole Ubuntu server system, so please take this issue into consideration. I have no problem in taking the time to work in required settings updates, I just would like to follow some step-by-step or at the very least some precise information about critical setps, even before the removal of the old NIC. Therefore, I would like to get instructions or suggestions group by BEFORE and AFTER NIC installation if possible.

It is important to mention that this are 2 servers which will get NIC upgrading; one is a host server for 2 virtual machines running on VirtualBox, also in production; the other is a backup file server with Webmin. It is also important to mention that I'm familiar with Linux command line BUT I'm not a Linux system manager.

Thank you so very much in advanced for helping and advising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 2022 and most PCIe server network adaptors *should* plug and play under Linux. How compatible the new device is with Ubuntu does depend on the chipset the new card uses (you haven't specified details of the new card in your question).

I would recommend searching for the model of your proposed upgrade hardware before ordering to see if the chipset has been well tested with Linux and whether there are any known issues.

Considering it's a production server, it could be wise to recreate an image of your host machine (or at least an install of the same version of Ubuntu) to test the network adaptor before you install it into the production.

I would suggest doing the upgrade on your backup server first! You can iron out any problems and the upgrade will be a lot slicker on the production box once you've practiced. Have a roll-back plan if it doesn't work out.

You may need to update `/etc/network/interfaces` once the new card is installed, if you're not using DHCP or you have other specific requirements for your network.

The configuration of your hypervisor and guests should be straighforward but I can't confirm this without more specifics on your configuration.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! There are indeed issues with the new NIC card and its drivers for Linux, despite what it is stated here: https://linuxreviews.org/TP-LINK_TG-3468_PCIe_Gigabit_Adapter. I will definitely follow your recommendations about working with the Ubuntu backup server first and evaluate results.